# Does exist an efficient algorithm to solve the equation $\ ax^2-cy-d=0$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Given the Diophantine equation: $\ ax^2-cy-d=0$ , the coefficients $\ c$ and $\ d$ are numbers in range of $\ 10^{300} $. Does exist an efficient way to find solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $ax^2 - d \equiv 0 \mod c$.  If $(a, c) = 1$, that says $x^2 \equiv d/a \mod c$.  So you need to solve the modular square root problem.  If $c$ is prime, that can be solved using the Tonelli-Shanks algorithm.  [If not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Composite_modulus_not_a_prime_power), you need to factor $c$.  For a number on the order of $10^{300}$, that may be beyond the reach of current technology.

Comment: What would happened if I take no notice about primality of $\ c $? I meant using Toneli-Shanks even $\ c $ isn't prime.

Answer (score 2):

It means $c|ay^2-d$
A requirement is that for any prime factor p of c, $\frac da$ is [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) of p, or both a and d are multiple of $p^h$ where $p^h | c$.
Given we have all prime factors of c and $\frac da$ is quadratic residue of all p, since there're [efficient algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) to solve square root in finite field, the equation could be solved efficently as soon as we could get all prime factors of c.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

ax^2-cy-d=0  -----(1)

For a=1, equation (1) has parametric solution:

x=(12k^2-14k+3)

y=(44k^2-24k+3)

c=(2k^2-6k+3)

d=2k(7k-3)(4k^2-1)

Since above solution is parametric even

if "OP" takes k=(10^300) he can still get

solution for equation (1) for [c,d]> (10^300)

Comment: Parametric solution of @Sam works and generates numbers which ones are the solutions of the equation, but I can't freely choose $\ c$ and $\ d$ because they are coupled together by parameter $\ k$.